# How to enable System.out.print() in JBoss EAP 6.2

Tags: jboss

I have just installed from scratch a JBoss Developer Studio 7.1.0 GA.

I coded a servlet like this:

```
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.print("test");
    }

...
}
```

Once ran, nothing is shown in the console, what is quite surprising!! Nor there is anything in /home/user/jbdevstudio/runtimes/jboss-eap/standalone/log directory.

The question is simple: How can I make System.out.print() print to the console?

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that System.out.print() does not work but System.out.println() does.

So it looks like it is simply that JBoss is waiting for the line to be completed.